# Are GPUCommandBuffer reusable? How to update input data buffers between invocations?

Tags: javascript, buffer, webgpu

It seems to me that I have to create a new GPUCommandBuffer every time I want to run the computation with different input values (either uniform or storage).

I tried loading new data into an existing staging buffer (with mapAsync) and running an existing command buffer (which starts with a copyBufferToBuffer). But the kernel only sees the old data, the new buffer never gets copied. Either that, or the computation never gets executed a second time.

If instead I create a new GPUCommandBuffer, identical to the old one, then it re-runs the computation using the new data.

What am I missing?

Here is the code. I'm using `passEncoder.endPass()` because I'm on Firefox trunk, if you're on Chromium you may have to replace it with `passEncoder.end()`

```js
if (!navigator.gpu) alert('WebGPU not supported.')

const adapter = await navigator.gpu.requestAdapter()
if (!adapter) alert('Couldn’t request WebGPU adapter.')

const device = await adapter.requestDevice()
if (!device) alert('Couldn’t request WebGPU device.')

// ------------------------------------------ GPU Kernel ------------------------------------------

// language=WGSL
const code = `
  @group(0) @binding(1) var<storage, read>       b1_input: array<f32>;
  @group(0) @binding(2) var<storage, read_write> b2_output: array<f32>;

  @compute @workgroup_size(64)
  fn main(
    @builtin(global_invocation_id) global_id: vec3<u32>,
  ) {
    if (global_id.x >= arrayLength(&b1_input)) {
      return;
    }
    b2_output[global_id.x] = b1_input[global_id.x] * 10.0;
  }
`

// ---------------------------------------- Create buffers ----------------------------------------

const { MAP_READ, MAP_WRITE, COPY_DST, STORAGE, COPY_SRC } = GPUBufferUsage

const b1_input_size = 4 * 10
const b1_input_gpu = device.createBuffer({ size: b1_input_size, usage: STORAGE | COPY_DST })
const b1_input_stage = device.createBuffer({ size: b1_input_size, usage: MAP_WRITE | COPY_SRC })

const b2_output_size = 4 * 10
const b2_output_gpu = device.createBuffer({ size: b2_output_size, usage: STORAGE | COPY_SRC })
const b2_output_stage = device.createBuffer({ size: b2_output_size, usage: MAP_READ | COPY_DST })

// --------------------------------------- Create pipeline ----------------------------------------

const bindGroupLayout = device.createBindGroupLayout({
  entries: [
    { binding: 1, visibility: GPUShaderStage.COMPUTE, buffer: { type: 'read-only-storage' } },
    { binding: 2, visibility: GPUShaderStage.COMPUTE, buffer: { type: 'storage' } },
  ],
})

const bindGroup = device.createBindGroup({
  layout: bindGroupLayout,
  entries: [
    { binding: 1, resource: { buffer: b1_input_gpu } },
    { binding: 2, resource: { buffer: b2_output_gpu } },
  ],
})

const pipeline = device.createComputePipeline({
  layout: device.createPipelineLayout({ bindGroupLayouts: [bindGroupLayout] }),
  compute: { module: device.createShaderModule({ code }), entryPoint: 'main' },
})

// -------------------------- Function to create a new GPUCommandBuffer ---------------------------

const workgroupCount = 1

function createCommandBuffer() {
  const commandEncoder = device.createCommandEncoder()

  commandEncoder.copyBufferToBuffer(b1_input_stage, 0, b1_input_gpu, 0, b1_input_size)

  const passEncoder = commandEncoder.beginComputePass()
  passEncoder.setPipeline(pipeline)
  passEncoder.setBindGroup(0, bindGroup)
  passEncoder.dispatchWorkgroups(workgroupCount)
  passEncoder.endPass()

  commandEncoder.copyBufferToBuffer(b2_output_gpu, 0, b2_output_stage, 0, b2_output_size)

  return commandEncoder.finish()
}

// ------------------------------------------ Executions ------------------------------------------

document.write('<pre>')

let input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
document.write(`Loading input = ${input}\n`)
await b1_input_stage.mapAsync(GPUMapMode.WRITE)
new Float32Array(b1_input_stage.getMappedRange()).set(input)
b1_input_stage.unmap()

document.write('\nExecuting GPUCommandBuffer\n')
let commands = createCommandBuffer()
device.queue.submit([commands])

await b2_output_stage.mapAsync(GPUMapMode.READ)
let output = new Float32Array(b2_output_stage.getMappedRange()).slice()
b2_output_stage.unmap()
document.write(`Output: ${output}\n\n`)

input = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
document.write(`Loading input = ${input}\n`)
await b1_input_stage.mapAsync(GPUMapMode.WRITE)
new Float32Array(b1_input_stage.getMappedRange()).set(input)
b1_input_stage.unmap()

document.write('\nExecuting the same GPUCommandBuffer\n')
device.queue.submit([commands])

await b2_output_stage.mapAsync(GPUMapMode.READ)
output = new Float32Array(b2_output_stage.getMappedRange()).slice()
b2_output_stage.unmap()
document.write(`Output: ${output} (WRONG?)\n`)

document.write('\nExecuting a new GPUCommandBuffer\n')
commands = createCommandBuffer()
device.queue.submit([commands])

await b2_output_stage.mapAsync(GPUMapMode.READ)
output = new Float32Array(b2_output_stage.getMappedRange()).slice()
b2_output_stage.unmap()
document.write(`Output: ${output}\n\n`)
```

Here is what I get:

```
Loading input = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

Executing GPUCommandBuffer
Output: 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100

Loading input = 2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20

Executing the same GPUCommandBuffer
Output: 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100 (WRONG?)

Executing a new GPUCommandBuffer
Output: 20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180,200
```

By the way, the problem is not with `read-only-storage`. I tried with all 3 buffer types and I get the same results.

Answer (score 1):

Only the `GPURenderBundle` can reuse the `GPUCommandBuffer`, but the GPURenderBundle is only used for rendering.

Looking at [submit(...) in WebGPU Spec](https://gpuweb.github.io/gpuweb/#dom-gpuqueue-submit), it is explicitly mentioned that a submitted cmdBuffer cannot be reused:

> Schedules the execution of the command buffers by the GPU on this queue.
>
> Submitted command buffers cannot be used again.